# Detaching user data snapshot listeners on web app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have a snapshot listener that listen for real time changes on user data I'm storing with Firestore. The listener is there due to a chat feature I am developing because I need to update the list of chat Id's that the user has in realtime in case a new chat was added. The problem is with detaching the listener when the user is **disconnected** or has lost connection. Any suggestions on how I could achieve this without using the **onDisconnect** method from Real Time DB since I can't call the `detachListner()` method with that.

Example:

here is my user doc

```
{
    name:"Brad"
    avatar:"https://avatar.com"
    chats: [
        {
            id: 1.,
            member_name:"John",
            avatar:""
        },
        {
            id: 2.,
            member_name:"John",
            avatar:""
        },
     ]
}
```

I have an active snapshot listener on this doc,

```
let unsubscribeListener;

export const getChatSnapshot = (user_id, callback) => {
  unsubscribeChatListener = onSnapshot(
    doc(db, "users", user_id),
    (doc) => {
      callback(doc.data());
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  );
};
```

is there  a way disconnect the listener when user disconnect or close the page.
since with **onDisconnect** I only have set, delete ...

Is there a way to have something like this.

```
onDisconnect(userStatusDatabaseRef)
// call unsubscribeListener when user is disconnected.
// like unsubscribeListener()
      .set(isOfflineForDatabase)
      .then(() => {
        set(userStatusDatabaseRef, isOnlineForDatabase);
      });
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Unless you are looking for https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can perform a write to Firestore after the user disconnections, similar to Realtime Database's `onDisconnect` handlers, the answer is unfortunately no.

Firestore uses a different protocol than Realtime Database, and that protocol doesn't allow for detecting the first connection or disconnecting. If you need those features within Firebase, Realtime Database is your only option.

Keep in mind that you can use both Firestore and Realtime Database in the same application. In fact, there's a solution guide that explains how to [build a presence system on Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) using Realtime Database and Cloud Functions behind the scenes.

Comment: My question was can I use the onDisconnect function to detach my listener ?

Comment: `onDisconnect` handlers run on the server after the client has already disconnected. At that point, there is no way for the server to call back into your client-side code and tell it to unsubscribe. If you want to detect client-side when the connection to the Realtime Database is lost, you can listen to the `.info/connected` node: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state